# Is it possible to use a directive again inside its own template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, angularjs-directive, javascript-framework

Im trying to write a 'comments' directive in angular to load nested comments(from Json data) and reuse the same directive for child comments/replies.

The parent comments load just fine by themselves, however when I try to show child comments by using the 'comments' directive again inside its own template, the app just freezes and I have to close it down.

Below is some of my code:

app.html: ---

```
  <ul ng-repeat="comment in View2.postItems | limitTo: 10">

    <comments collection="comment"></comments>

  </ul>
```

comments.html (directive):----

```
<li>      
  <span>
    {{ collection.data.commentText }}

    <ul ng-show="{{collection.data.replies}}"
        ng-repeat="comment in collection.data.replies.data.children">

      <!-**child comments: this line causes the app to freeze:**-->
      <comments collection="comment"></comments>

    </ul>

  </span>
</li>
```

comments.js:---

```
var comments = function(){
  return {
    templateUrl : 'modules/comments/comments.html',
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
      collection: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build recursive directives with the `$compile` service to conditionally append the child directive. Example: (http://plnkr.co/edit/WpNp20DSjJhO412j3cSw?p=preview)

```
function comment($compile) {
    return {
      template: '<span ng-bind="comment.text"></span>',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        if (angular.isArray(scope.comment.collection)) {
              element.append($compile('<comments collection="comment.collection"></comments>')(scope));
        }
      }
    }
}

function comments(){
  return {
    template : '<ul><li ng-repeat="comment in collection"><comment></comment></li></ul>',
    scope:{
      collection: '='
    }
  };
}
```